# Is is possible to calling a logic apps from another logic apps without using a http trigger

Tags: azure-logic-apps

One way to trigger a logic apps from another logic apps is using http trigger other than this any trigger available to call another logic apps from a logic apps

Comment: Can you provide any more details

Comment: just for learning I am trying azure logic apps .  I have to trigger a logic app from another logic apps. I have done with Http trigger in parent logic apps I put a http request and in chield logic app I put a trigger when a http request received and there i send a http response  and executed successfully. My requirement like is this possible to use any other trigger in chield logic apps instead of http trigger ?

Comment: Yep, you can decouple and use queues. Be careful though, you may lose traceability.

Answer (score 0):

> [Is is possible to calling a logic apps from another logic apps without using a http trigger

Yes, you can call using  another service and then by using that service trigger we can call another logic apps.

Lets say a logic app sends a message to a queue in Service bus, in next logic app you need to use below trigger:

[image]

Or in 1st logic app send a file to storage account and in new logic app use that container and Event Grid trigger as below:

[image]

So this way you can call, here at calling step in 1st logic app you need to create dummy file in storage account or rename or send a  message to service bus queue and in 2nd logic app use service bus trigger, you can use event triggers, these some of the ways to call another logic app, easy way is using http trigger.