# How to call a workflow from another logic app?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

In my current project, I'm dealing with standard logic apps. Within one of these logic apps, I've set up a specific workflow. Now, I'm looking to initiate or trigger a different workflow, but this secondary workflow resides in a separate standard logic app. I'm seeking guidance on the process of calling or invoking this second workflow from a different logic app.

Comment: Just use a HTTP connector or decouple it with queues or something. There’s no specific operation to link the call to a workflow in another app.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with @Skin that you can use http trigger in one logic app workflow and then call it from http action from another workflow like below:

[image]

The above one works if the 1st workflow uses below trigger:

[image]

Or refer this [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77140025/17623802) for more information. You can also send message to queue and use a queue trigger or service bus queue trigger.